# ¿Como comparar promedio en un where?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, join

Estoy utilizando la base de datos sakila en Mysql y quiero obtener las categorías que tengan el promedio de duración de sus películas,por encima del promedio de duración de todas las películas del catálogo

Esta consulta me devuelve el promedio por categorias

```
select cat.name,avg(f.length) from film f
    join film_category fc on fc.film_id=f.film_id
    join category cat on cat.category_id=fc.category_id
    group by cat.category_id
```

Y si hago un

```
select avg(f.length) from film f
```

obtengo el promedio de duracion de las peliculas registradas
Mi problema es que no se como realizar la comparacion entre los promedios por categoria y el promedio de la duracion de la peliculas para que solo muestre las categorias que tengan el pomedio mayor que el de todas las peliculas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pues solo te falta un having!!!

para sacar las filas dentro de un group by que cumplen la condición, una vez calculada las condiciones, se usa having...

y dado que ya tenes el promedio que vos queres, un acercamiento rápido seria:

```
select cat.name,avg(f.length) from film f
join film_category fc on fc.film_id=f.film_id
join category cat on cat.category_id=fc.category_id
group by cat.category_id
having avg(f.length) > (select avg(f.length) from film f)
```